# Вывод записей определенной подкатегории WP

Tags: wordpress

У меня есть основная категория и в ней 2 подкатегории записи которых нужно выводить в разных местах. То есть записи с одной подкатегории в одном месте, записи с другой в другом. Не пойму как вывести записи из конкретной подкатегории. Пока код выглядит так

```
function getSale(){

        $args = array(
            'category_name' => 'high_nozzles',
            'orderby'     => 'date',
            'order'       => 'DESC',
            'post_type'   => 'sale',
        );

        $postSales = [];

        foreach (get_posts($args) as $post) {
            $postSale = get_fields($post->ID);
            $postSale["title"] = $post->post_title;
            $postSale["content"] = $post->post_content;
            $postSale["img"] = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post->ID, 'full' );
            $postSales[] = $postSale;
        }

        return $postSales;
}
```

"high_nozzles" это название подкатегории, но если выводит через var_dump эту функцию, то пишет что массив пуст.

Comment: Если ты работаешь с кастомным типом постов то у тебя их категории - это не совсем категории самого WP. Они, как бе - отдельные таксономии. Их надо вытаскивать через `tax_query`. Вот тут пример есть https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49185/tax-query-parameter-not-working-with-wp-query

Comment: Что значит "в одном" и "другом" местах? Какая конкретно задача?  Расшифруй это, исправив вопрос.

Comment: @РашенБеар помогло, спасибо)Остался только вопрос, как с помощью tax_query не выводить запись из подрубрики? То есть я хочу сделать так, что бы была одна общая рубрика у которой 2 подрубрики, записи одной выводим, но если человек выберет для одной записи сразу обе подрубрики, то такие записи не выводить

Comment: @Alexa тут тебе могу посоветовать читать документацию (ну хоть в не оф. источниках) и пробовать ее понимать.